# Leaflet setting zoom level for specified geoJSON layer property

Tags: javascript, leaflet, zooming, geojson

I would like to set a separate zoom level for some specified geoJSON property layer in leaflet.

I used a following code (as per the continuation of this process):
[Setting zoom level for layers in leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58629387/setting-zoom-level-for-layers-in-leaflet)

```
   map.on('zoomend', function() {
   if (map.getZoom() <6){
        map.removeLayer(mylayer);
     }else{
    map.addLayer(mylayer);
    }
  });
```

which is applicable for a geoJSON layer right? 
When zoom is lower than 6, the layer is gone.

I would like to do the same for some `feature.property` included in this GeoJSON layer.

I tried something like this then:

```
  map.on('zoomend', function() {
      if (map.getZoom() <8){
        map.removeLayer(feature.properties.Capacity>=40);
       }else{
        map.addLayer(feature.properties.Capacity>=40);
        }
       });
```

but unfortunately the result is terrible. Instead of working function, all of my points are floating across the map when flipping zoom level up and down.

The console states:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: feature is not defined
>       at i. ((index):173)
>       at i.fire (leaflet.js:5)
>       at i._moveEnd (leaflet.js:5)
>       at i. (leaflet.js:5) (anonymous) @ (index):173 fire @ leaflet.js:5
>   _moveEnd @ leaflet.js:5 (anonymous) @ leaflet.js:5 requestAnimationFrame (async) M @ leaflet.js:5
>   _onZoomTransitionEnd @ leaflet.js:5 setTimeout (async)
>   _animateZoom @ leaflet.js:5 (anonymous) @ leaflet.js:5 requestAnimationFrame (async) M @ leaflet.js:5
>   _tryAnimatedZoom @ leaflet.js:5 setView @ leaflet.js:5 setZoomAround @ leaflet.js:5
>   _performZoom @ leaflet.js:5 setTimeout (async)
>   _onWheelScroll @ leaflet.js:5 s @ leaflet.js:5 2

which I don't really understand, because the geoJSON layer has been fetched to the map.

Could you help me to solve this problem?[image]

Something close to the stuff, that I am looking for is here:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41928/adding-removing-leaflet-geojson-layers

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239795/leaflet-remove-filtered-layer

that lead me to the 3rd attempt, unfortunately in vain

```
  map.on('zoomend', function() {
     if (map.getZoom() <6){
    if (feature.properties.Capacity >=40){
        map.removeLayer(feature.properties.Capacity);
     }else{
     map.addLayer(feature.properties.Capacity);
     }
   });
```

Another my attempts you can see under this link:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341684/leaflet-setting-zoom-level-for-a-specified-geojson-layer-feature

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the animation is bugging out, just set zoomanimation to zero.

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-zoomanimation

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for you advice, although it still doesn't work.
I put zoomAnimation: false into my map options, but the result is the same. At least I know, that here is a clash between map.on (zoomend, function) and zoomAnimation option. Tried also with zoomAnimationThreshold - no result.
Console states the same.
Have you got another ideas? Thanks

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: feature is not defined at i. ((index):173) show me this line

Comment: This is exactly:
   map.removeLayer(feature.properties.Capacity>=40);

Comment: No, the actual error trace. This line isnt even 173 characters long

Comment: This number states about the line number not a length of the characters:

Comment: Then it just means feature is undefined. Do a console log on feature

Comment: This is the thing, that I don't understand. WHy the feature is undefined, when belongs to geoJSON layer attached to the map?

Comment: you are not sharing enough to let me tell you why. Just debug it and figure out when feature became undefined

Comment: Well,

Please take a look on my JSFiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Krukarius/h7L2vxem/2/

I haven't attached my .geojson file only. Anyway you have my entire code now.

Comment: map.on('zoomend', function() {
    if (map.getZoom() <8){
            map.removeLayer(feature.properties.Capacity>=40);
    }else{
  map.addLayer(feature.properties.Capacity>=40);
  }
}); where is the feature defined???

Comment: OK, if it's not. Could you write down the proposal place, where to use it?