# Clickable zoom in leaflet to open new leaflet geometry and plot new geometry

Tags: r, leaflet

I have some data which looks like:

```
# A tibble: 52 × 3
   provincia     mean_price number_properties
   <chr>              <dbl>             <int>
 1 A Coruña         179833.              2508
 2 Albacete         148584.              1311
 3 Alicante         418148.             22676
 4 Almería          142338.              3902
 5 Araba - Álava    243705.               786
```

I can get the geospatial data using:

```
library(mapSpain)

# read in and match data, then order provincias data
provincias <- mapSpain::esp_get_prov() %>%
  sf::st_transform(provincias, crs = 4326)
```

This is for the "province" level - each province can contain "municipalities". There is a function in the `mapSpain` package to get the same geospatial data as provinces but for municipalities.

```
mapSpain::esp_get_munic(region = "Barcelona")
```

I am trying to create an interactive leaflet map such that when the user clicks on a "province" it will zoom in and show the "municipality" data for that province.

```
leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.Toner) %>%
  addPolygons(data = provincias)  # change here on update
  )
```

So, we click on one of the provinces and that would take us to the zoomed `mapSpain::esp_get_munic(region = "Barcelona")` We can "zoom-in" to the Barcelona region by adding   `setView(lng = 2.154007, lat =  41.390205, zoom = 12)` to the `leaflet` plot.

[image]

After clicking on one of the provinces, it would run something like the following:

```
municipios <- mapSpain::esp_get_prov() %>%
  sf::st_transform(municipios, crs = 4326)

leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.Toner) %>% 
  setView(lng = 2.154007, lat =  41.390205, zoom = 9) %>% 
  addPolygons(data = municipios)
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(provincia = c("A Coruña", "Albacete", "Alicante", 
"Almería", "Araba - Álava", "Asturias", "Badajoz", "Barcelona", 
"Bizkaia", "Burgos", "Cantabria", "Castellón", "Ceuta", "Ciudad Real", 
"Cuenca", "Cáceres", "Cádiz", "Córdoba", "Gipuzkoa", "Girona", 
"Granada", "Guadalajara", "Huelva", "Huesca", "Illes Balears", 
"Jaén", "La Rioja", "Las Palmas", "León", "Lleida", "Lugo", 
"Madrid", "Melilla", "Murcia", "Málaga", "Navarra", "Ourense", 
"Palencia", "Pontevedra", "Salamanca", "Santa Cruz de Tenerife", 
"Segovia", "Sevilla", "Soria", "Tarragona", "Teruel", "Toledo", 
"Valencia", "Valladolid", "Zamora", "Zaragoza", "Ávila"), mean_price = c(179833.167862839, 
148583.87109077, 418148.151437643, 142337.792926704, 243704.750636132, 
149179.732438607, 147802.894486692, 462813.775190776, 286461.604484305, 
134635.540239044, 201214.437926878, 139819.15323646, 204318.181818182, 
113856.401715511, 116992.998609179, 143137.441025641, 251270.65520481, 
166586.746650426, 340663.440746753, 365733.360551724, 219325.194605466, 
173221.569037657, 142430.992912371, 141754.603535354, 749037.540922619, 
131396.292428198, 160838.235963581, 656553.777123633, 140312.919506463, 
160485.155614973, 129787.667711599, 433665.652781242, 234306.12244898, 
188635.237652749, 687127.622056842, 197388.050991501, 137829.640394089, 
123450.853813559, 230344.604904632, 159999.046077894, 328912.419004007, 
184829.536144578, 180692.511036468, 155759.235955056, 193651.956693536, 
128909.006756757, 132623.629553967, 177825.529404212, 165240.297002725, 
116820.125531915, 164934.932635983, 124977.724215247), number_properties = c(2508L, 
1311L, 22676L, 3902L, 786L, 3502L, 2104L, 35906L, 3345L, 1255L, 
2489L, 4542L, 44L, 1399L, 719L, 1170L, 5322L, 5747L, 1232L, 7250L, 
16906L, 956L, 1552L, 396L, 5376L, 1915L, 1318L, 2378L, 1702L, 
1870L, 638L, 16036L, 49L, 7856L, 15587L, 706L, 1421L, 472L, 2569L, 
1823L, 3494L, 498L, 6252L, 89L, 6327L, 296L, 2937L, 15576L, 1468L, 
470L, 2390L, 446L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-52L))
```

ShinyApp:

```
library(shiny)
library(mapSpain)
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)
library(powerjoin)
library(purrr)
library(fuzzyjoin)

# ... load "df" data

# read in and match data, then order provincias data
provincias <- mapSpain::esp_get_prov() %>%
  sf::st_transform(provincias, crs = 4326)


ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    dataTableOutput(outputId = "leaflet_table")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  ### if on.click == "Barcelona" - zoom and open;
  #### mapSpain::esp_get_munic(region = "Barcelona")
  ##### Zoom in on this area of the map.
  
  output$leaflet_table = renderLeaflet(
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.Toner) %>%
      addPolygons(data = provincias)  # change here on update
  )

}
```

R Code:

```
df

library(mapSpain)

# read in and match data, then order provincias data
provincias <- mapSpain::esp_get_prov() %>%
  sf::st_transform(provincias, crs = 4326)


leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.Toner) %>%
  addPolygons(data = provincias)  # change here on update
```

**EDIT:**

I realise `df` is not needed here but I leave it in the post. All of the data can be collected through the `mapSpain` package.

Comment: Have you tried using `groupOptions` and `zoomLevels` like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61503281/display-layers-at-certain-zoom-levels-in-r-leaflet) answer?